# In excel sheet I have a column that contains the mobile number of all countries, I want the mobile numbers of each country in a separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In the excel sheet, I have a column that contains the mobile number of all countries, I want the mobile numbers of each country in a separate column

**my data**
[image: my data]

**desired results**
[image]

image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDZ3U.png) is the data I have and I want this data to be like image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUDFD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make a country phone code Data sheet on excel like as follow;

[image]

After that create numbers sheet on same excel and write your numbers and then use this formula on B2 cell
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A2,4)),Data!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A2,3)),Data!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A2,2)),Data!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A2,1)),Data!A:B,2,0),"?"))))`

This formula will return the country names that your phone data matches as follow;

[image]

Change name of table on the Numbers page as myData and make column A as numbers from Format Cells options.
Make your country names transpose on another page and use this formula;

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Numbers!$A:$B,SMALL(IF((A1=myData[Countries]),ROW(myData[Countries])),ROW(myData[Countries])-1),{1}),"")
```

and then copy this formula all row for each country. Done!

This is that you want.
(Note: I change the format cell as phone number on PivotTable sheet)

[image]

Comment: First of all you should change the Data sheet in your linked excel file. Country Code should be on column A. Country Name should be on column B and then use the formula that I write on answer. Please look at the pictures!

Comment: I have another question that can we do this on multiple sheets at the same time?

Comment: I have already given you an upvote but as I am now I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote my feedback was recorded when I get 15 reputations StackOverflow gives you an upvote.

Comment: I tried to get the reputation as early as possible

Comment: Sir please help me

Comment: Online Excel platform does not support table name due to can not use that formula.
Download the link to your computer and open it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYdrHa_B4dV-26NxyuQUYSNc8sXJdB7T/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118070475370252666199&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: sir i tried to open this link but failed they said Request Sent
You'll get an email letting you know if the file is shared with you

Comment: but i get no email. and in tab bar Access denied is written

Comment: Sir, I have sent you an email with which file link attached may be from Gmail or iCloud check it pleases. I had removed the file link from here because whenever I opened the excel was hung.

Comment: I  think I could only access this file when you send me its link through email.

Comment: Sir, I am using desktop excel nor an online one. I again try to do it at this time formula work but only for two cells. Check it, please

Comment: I think you do not need a link to open the file.

Comment: Sir, send me this google doc from email. So I can be able to access it.

Comment: I changed the priority settings. You can access it.

Comment: Sir, I found the problem with the formula. There is a slight difference in your and mine formula. I send you an email to check it and the file link is attached to it.

Comment: This is not an individual platform, can you please share your error and how the solution was.

Comment: I want to comment a picture so I can tell the problem how can I do that. that's why i send you an email

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rnwHapR

Comment: this is the link of picture check it

Comment: please check it